# Slip Frequency Factors In Indirect Field Oriented Control

Tags: induction-motor, vector-control

I am attempting to configure a asynchronous motor with a IFOC drive.  I have an encoder on the motor, however I have been struggling with getting the drive parameterized to operate correctly.

My issue seemed to be that there was no effective torque beyond a particular speed and beyond this point, the motor could only accelerate very slowly.   I ruled out issues with field weakening, because this was happening before I hit the specified field weakening range.  I noticed that during acceleration, if I plotted the direct and quadrature measured voltages of the vector control, the direct component would drop as the quadrature component increased.  From my understanding, the direct component should remain consistent as the quadrature increased.

I cross referenced as many motor parameters from the motor mfg. to the drive mfg., but I did not have sufficient information to fill the Rotor Time Constant in which I understood to be the Rotor Inductance / Rotor Resistance.  I tried lowering this value from the default of 109 ms to 25 ms and noticed I was now able to accelerate with ample available torque and the direct component stays much more consistent.  I have gone back to the motor mfg. and they supplied me with a rotor inductance of 11.2 mH and I already had a rotor resistance of 0.14 ohm.  I think this leaves a rotor time constant of about 80 ms which is closer to the 109 ms default, and when I was testing I noticed at 50 ms I still had issues.

My questions are:

- How should I go about determining the correct factor for this?
- What other factors of the motor model may be incorrectly offsetting this?
- Is this correct the 0.0112 Henry over 0.14 ohm is 80 ms?

Comment: I would recommend that you add some schematics of some sort, and possibly links to some datasheets/ app-notes etc., also adding a bit of background theory about IFOC could help people answer your question as well. I have worked with FOC before, but I have never heard of IFOC, how do they differ?

Comment: I can add information as needed but at this point I wasn't sure what would be useful.  By IFOC I am talking about Field Oriented Control when the Flux Linkage Orientation is estimated based on the Motor Model not a measurement within the air gap.  I understand there are 2 main forms of Field Oriented Control (D)irect FOC and (I)ndirect FOC mine being the latter

Comment: "based on the Motor Model not a measurement within the air gap", I don't understand what you mean by that, within the air gap? how would you even do that?.. As I sayed I have worked with FOC before (just plain old textbook FOC) and it uses an encoder on the back of the motor, coupled directly to the shaft, to determine the orientation of the field. To me it sounds like you've got an encoder (quadrature?) on the back of the motor, in which case you should just implement standard FOC. I still don't understand what IFOC is supposed to be, is it something you read about or a term you came up with?

Comment: "There are two vector control methods, direct or feedback vector control (DFOC) and indirect or feedforward vector control (IFOC)"  - From Wikipedia I believe that they measure the flux with additional windings placed within the motor for measuring the actual flux orientation

Comment: [Explanation Of Methods Of Field Oriented Control](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/1549/1b64442c63f3c337e2e47960fa2e59c08810.pdf)

Comment: "feedforward vector control" If it is "feedforward" then it can't be "field oriented.." in my oppinion, at least I don't see how, and I also didn't find anything relevant related to this in the article you linked to.. Sorry but I think you have found a red herring on wikipedia, that is; the article was probably written by someone who thought he new more than he did.

Comment: Also "Slip Frequency Factors.." in FOC the frequency doesn't "slip", it is controlled by a feedback loop which determines where the field is, hence it doesn't slip, hence it is FOC, that is the very purpose of FOC, this is also why I don't understand how FOC could ever be "feedforward"?. From your answers I kind of get the feeling that you don't really know enough about FOC to implement it, sorry.

Comment: [Another Example](https://www.st.com/en/applications/industrial-motor-control/3-phase-field-oriented-control-foc.html)  I certainly did not invent this term.  Almost every paper I read on Field Oriented Control references the 2 main types.  Furthermore I don't see how feedforward has anything to do with this.  From my understanding FOC has more to do with the fact that using transforms you can move the three phase AC system into 2 orthogonal components representing torque and flux

Comment: You absolutely have slip.  A encoder will only measure current rotor position however your flux angle will slip on the rotor.  That is the difference between Synchronous and Asynchronous motors.  In order to implement the FOC you must know the angle of the Flux which will not be Synchronous with the rotor position in an Asynchronous Motor

Comment: "From my understanding FOC has more to do with the fact that using transforms you can move the three phase AC system into 2 orthogonal components representing torque and flux" This technique is used in many types of motor control, not just FOC, from MY understanding of FOC; what makes it FOC is that you control those two phases (orthogonal components) based on the instantanious ORIENTATION of the FIELD of the rotor, hence Field Oriented Control, and you do that by measuring the instantanious angle of the field in a feedback loop..

Comment: "...and you do that by measuring the instantanious angle of the field in a feedback loop..",  And how does one do this with an induction motor with an encoder.  Rotor position alone is not enough because there will be slip hence forth Asynchronous motor.  With Synchronous AC motors this problem is trivial because rotor position has a fixed offet(commutation angle)from the Flux

Comment: Sorry I didn't read your question well enough before commenting, I have only worked with FOC for synchronous motors, where the angle of the field does absolutely corrospond 1:1 with the angle of the shaft. However I still don't get how FOC could ever be implemented without feedback.

Comment: I believe that the inductive reactance of the rotor should be calculated using the slip frequency at rated torque where slip frequency is determined from slip RPM equals synchronous RPM minus RPM at rated torque.

Comment: @Vinzent most modern FOC control of induction machine use predictive algorithm with the harmonic presents in the currents of the stator to determine the rotor flux angle & magnitude. The paper provided by MDK is just a gimmick, there is no such thing as direct and indirect FOC. The direct FOC mention in the paper is an university case, literally the flux is never measure in real life.... You are also right, MDK doesn't have enough experience with FOC to implement it in an induction machine.

Comment: The first step would be to implement a FOC with a PMSM which is easiest case and to understand the behavior of id & iq with the machine.... The next step is to implement FOC in a induction machine with a control of the field. Finaly, than you can implement FOC on a induction machine. Induction are way more complex to control because the id or iq component (depending on your transformation method) cannot be equal to 0 like on an induction machine because you need to provide VAR to create the rotating field.